# Laravel - How to show JSON response after changing HTTP method in Postman?

Tags: json, laravel, postman

I have an API, and there is a login method with POST request type, so when I hit the API path in postman with POST request type it works fine, but when I change the request type to GET it shows an error, I want to show JSON response here, how to do that

This is with POST method

[image: This is with POST method]

This is with GET method

[image: This is with GET method]

Comment: What do type of JSON response do you want to show there? Form data should be sent using POST request, and not a GET request.

Comment: Please post the login method

Comment: @Akar Thanks for the reply, I want to show the response in JSON format means `{Message: HTTP method is not correct}`, instead of the HTML response.

Comment: Change the route to the API method to GET i.e. Route::get()

Comment: @aphoe Thanks for the reply, then I will have the same issue with POST request.

Comment: Have you tried to change your .env file to `APP_ENV=production`?

Comment: @Akar nope bro.

Comment: @shashiverma then you can have two routes pointing to the same method. One will be a GET, the other POST

Comment: @aphoe then what if I have 100 routes?

Answer (score 1):

I think you route "api/auth/singup" accept only POST request, 
you have to look the route file, and allow GET method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it has a POST request, and I want to keep it as a POST, please read my question once again.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "_method" in the POST body.

The _method param can take [GET, POST, PUT, DELETE] values.

Example :

```
_method: GET
name: xxxx
email: xxxx@xxx.com
password: 123xxx
```

Comment: bhai, I want to show a response when I put the wrong request method in postman.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the exception in `App\Exceptions\Handler` like below:

```
// if (request()->expectsJson())
// Or if you want to handle just for `api` routs:
if(request()->is('api/*')) {
    if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedExceptionFormatter) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'your message here'], 405);
    }
}
```

But if you want to allow both `GET & POST` requests through your route you can do this in your `web.php` file :

```
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], 'login', 'YourController@method');
```

And then in your controller do this:

```
function yourMethod () {
    if (request()->method() == \Illuminate\Http\Request::METHOD_GET) {
        // do this;
    }
    else if (request()->method() == \Illuminate\Http\Request::METHOD_POST) {
        // do that;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have done this. I think this is used when our API route is wrong or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In your `api.php` file add a general route to catch any unmatched routes and send your error from there.

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    $data = [
        'error' => [
            'message' => 'Unkown endpoint',
            'statusCode' => 404
        ]
    ];
    return Response::json($data, 404);
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it only works with the HTTP requests, if I change the endpoint of API it shows the same error as image 2.